# I want to know why the hover is not working

Tags: css

I want to know why the hover is not working.
I got this css but when add command hover css doesn't work.

```
      <style>

.gelatine :hover{
  animation:  gelatine 0.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes gelatine {
  from, to { transform: scale(1, 1); }
  25% { transform: scale(0.9, 1.1); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.1, 0.9); }
  75% { transform: scale(0.95, 1.05); }
}

</style>



</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img class="gelatine" src="video-icon-1.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the space between `.gelatine` and `:hover`